# Problem with Server-Client application on Kotlin

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, kotlin, server

I have a simple Client-Server application. The client is written as Android Project and Server is Gradle Kotlin Project. Here is client code(written as AsyncTask):

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Player){
    try {
        clientSocket = Socket(host, port)

        val writer = PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true)
        writer.write(serializer.toJson(params[0]))
        writer.flush()

        writer.close()
        clientSocket.close()
    }catch(e: Exception){
        Log.e(TAG, e.message)
    }
}
```

Here is the server code:

```
Thread {
        while (true) {
            val client = serverSocket.accept()
            val inputAsString = client.getInputStream().bufferedReader().use { it.readLine() }
            val player = serializer.fromJson<Player>(inputAsString)
            val connection = UserConnection(client, player, Response(ResponseType.SUCCESS, fetchedText, players))
            val thread = Thread(connection)
            thread.apply { isDaemon = true }.start()
        }

    }.start()
```

And UserConnection class:

```
class UserConnection(private val connection: Socket, private val player: Player, var response: Response) :
Runnable {

private var connected = true

private val serializer = Gson()

override fun run() {

    if(connection.isClosed){
        connected = false
        println("client of player ${player.userName} is closed!!!")
    }

    while (connected) {
        val writer = PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true)
        println(serializer.toJson(response))
        writer.write(serializer.toJson(response))
    }
}
```

Don't concern about Player, Response and ResponseType. They are just data models, and serialization is working well.

The problem is that Socket is always closed after accepting and UserConnection Thread is not running so i always see "client of player ${user.userName} is closed!!!"

P.S. I tried not to close Socket on client(it's automatically closing after closing OutputStream). Without closing OutputStream on client, Server does not read data(flush is not working too)

Comment: Tried joining the top level thread to main?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line:

```
val inputAsString = client.getInputStream().bufferedReader().use { it.readLine() }
```

It reads all data from stream and closes the stream, meanwhile InputStream is closed, socket closes automatically.
Instead of it i use this:

```
val inputAsString = client.getInputStream().reader().readText()
```